# Import xml scheme from url to file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, xsd

I have generated a client from a web service in my `Java EE` project which generates the following code.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "base64Binary", propOrder = {
"value"
})  public class Base64Binary {

@XmlValue
protected byte[] value;
@XmlAttribute(name = "contentType", namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime")
protected String contentType;
```

My issue is the call to `http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime` gets blocked by our firewall.  Changing the call to `https` doesn't work because it gets redirected to `http`.  I would like to import the xml scheme contained at `http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime` into a file in my project and change the `namespace` value to the file.  The schema contained at `http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime` is

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime"
       targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" >

  <xs:attribute name="contentType">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string" >
      <xs:minLength value="3" />
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:attribute>

  <xs:attribute name="expectedContentTypes" type="xs:string" />

  <xs:complexType name="base64Binary" >
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:base64Binary" >
            <xs:attribute ref="xmime:contentType" />
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="hexBinary" >
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:hexBinary" >
            <xs:attribute ref="xmime:contentType" />
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

I have found several questions about this issue and making a local copy seems to be the accepted solution, but since the schema file itself references the `http` urls in

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime"
       targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" >
```

I am not sure how to change it to make everything point to my local copy.

Answer (score 1):

This question shows my ignorance of xml.  The issue was not with the code I listed but in a different file where it was importing the schema.

```
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime"/>
```

I created a `wsd` file in the same folder as the `wsdl` file which contained the import code.  Then I copied xml from `http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime` and put it in the `wsd` file.  Then I changed the import code to

```
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" schemaLocation="nameOfLocalCopyOfXml.xsd"/>
```